# What is the point of holding a committee with an empty chair?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, rule-of-law

In [Don McGahn defies subpoena as Trump clash with Congress intensifies](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2019/may/21/don-mcgahn-defies-subpoena-congress-trump), the Guardian raises that:

> The House judiciary committee held a brief hearing on Tuesday morning in McGahn’s absence, with an empty chair where he was supposed to sit.

Is there any point in such theatricals beyond showcasing on CSPAN that McGahn didn't show up? Is there anything else to it (if so please provide data or at the very least put an excellent argument forward)? Or is it strictly about political theatrics (if so, likewise put an excellent argument forward as to why/how that is useful)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any point in such theatricals beyond showcasing on CSPAN that McGahn didn't show up?

No.

> Or is it strictly about political theatrics (if so, why/how is that useful)?

Generally speaking, Congressional candidates often take footage of themselves speaking on the floor or in public committee session, and use it to make advertisements for their re-election and/or fundraising pitches.

Jerrold Nadler is currently promoting himself on his campaign website as someone who was born to fight Donald Trump. Making a big angry spectacle about Don McGahn not showing up to a hearing is one way to show that he's doing something to fight Donald Trump.